# PHP header function redirects to a page which does not exist

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to redirect my page to another after a user logs in using PHP header function, but it keeps redirecting to a page which doesn't even exist. Let me explain more:

I have a php script called "admin_login.php" which has the following form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="admin_login.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Username</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="admin_login_username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="admin_login_password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-default">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

So when the user clicks "Submit" the same script "admin_login.php" is called and the required user login scripts run:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

if( $_POST["submit"] )
{

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_name = "global_electronics";

$connection = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);

$username =  $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE admin_username='$username' AND admin_password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

if( $result->num_rows > 0 )
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result );

    if( $username === $row['admin_username'] && $password === $row["admin_password"] )
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["admin_ID"] = $row["admin_id"];
        $_SESSION["admin_username"] = $username;

        header("Location:admin_home.php");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Incorrect Username or Password!";
    }

}
}
?>
```

If you see the header function in the previous script, it should redirect the page to "admin_home.php"
Instead it redirects the browser to "index.php" which doesn't even exist in my project folder.

When the "admin_login.php" is loaded in the browser:

```
http://localhost:63342/Global%20Electronics/admin_login.php
```

After clicking on submit:

```
http://localhost:63342/index.php
```

which also shows a 404 error

What is wrong with the code? Am I using the header function correctly? Am I missing something?

I also used, instead of the header function:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.top.location='../admin_home.php';</script>";
```

which also redirects me to "index.php"

NOTE:
I am using PhpStorm 8.0.3
Latest MySql Workbench running the wamp MySql database
My project is not located in Wamp it is located somewhere else

So what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your admin_login.php are in the same folder as your script. This code might be a problem. Two dots means previous directory, so use one dot in the file path.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.top.location='./admin_home.php';</script>";
```

Also, include a space in the header redirect location to see if that works.

`header("Location:admin_home.php");`

to

`header("Location: admin_home.php");`

Comment: this didn't help, it still redirects to "index.php" (which clearly does not exist)

Comment: My suspicion is the script looks for te admin_home.php it cant find so it defaults to DOCUMENT_ROOT. Try changing to  ```header("Location: Global%20Electronics/admin_login.php")```